# Python: manage libraries across different virtual env?

Tags: python, virtualenv

**Context**: I need to use many applications/libraries, examples include Airflow, Superset and Prefect. I learned that it's good practice to install them using Python virtualenv, so that the lib dependencies won't confict.

Now, suppose I've sucessfully installed these three libraries in three individual virtual envs, I'd like to use them in my main project, which is the default python enviroment. For example, I want to call some functions from either of the three libraries, or use one function from library B in enviroment A. **Is this possible and how to do it?**

**If this is not possible, is there other method to achieve my goal?** The dumb method would be to install all the libraries in the same env, but I'll need to carefully deal with the dependency issues. **What about using different dockers?**

Comment: `requirements.txt` is just what you need. Run `pip freeze > requirements.txt` on 1st virtualenv, it will give you the list of your dependencies and their version. Run `pip install -r requirements.txt` on other virtualenvs to install them. The only thing you have to do is to make sure that: all virtualenvs must be the same version.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use one Python environment per process. The standard approach is to install all of the libraries you need for your project in a single virtual environment. It may seem like the "dumb" approach, but dependency issues don't happen frequently in my experience.

I would try to install everything you need in one environment. Unless that doesn't work, there's no need to make things complicated by trying to use multiple environments.